# Update timePerFrame of SKAction animateWithTextures:timePerFrame:

Tags: sprite-kit

I need to refresh the timePerFrame parameter of an action (in update).
What is the property of the SKAction that manages that?

```
[SKAction animateWithTextures:sometextures timePerFrame:0.1];
```

- `speed` does not affect frame animation as it seems.
- `duration` can be inspected and it will tell the initial timePerFrame set * number of frames, so if you have eight frames and timePerFrame of 0.1 the duration will be 0.8. Setting the duration does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the time per frame, you have to reset the animation all together,  so you need to do some tricks like take the current texture of the sprite,  find out where it is in your animation,  then create a new array where your current texture is at point 0.  From what I can tell, there are no methods available to grab or set the point of index start for animations

Comment: That's what I feared too. It just feels like that could be too much work to do for every frame, but can still be worth a try if anything else fails. I want a sprite to have his "walk" animation play at a pace that is related to its movement speed on screen. Another option I am considering is to use custom actions, with the blocks. Possibly the frame changing logic can be put in that block, then the time per frame would be easy to change.

Comment: yeah,  that is an option as well

Comment: I ended up not using actions at all for this, just rolling my own frame changing logic within update. It was the most straightforward thing to do.